# I am having a problem with Android Application Runtime Error. I dont know why

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I originally changed everything with a px size to dp and sp. Then my app stopped working. Here is the link explaining that.

[In Android app,I changed all px to dp and sp. Now it is not opening. What is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554257/in-android-app-i-changed-all-px-to-dp-and-sp-now-it-is-not-opening-what-is-wron)

I have changed all the dp and sp back to px so now it should be working as it did before but it is displaying the same error messages and the same problems occur.  Below is the stack trace in the debugger. Can anyone help solve this problem?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/screenshot20110705at105.png/

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Did you replaced automatically, i.e. with "Find & Replace" all `px` with `dp`? If so, may be you replaced `px` in some ID or something. Check if that is the problem.

Comment: Ya I did do it automatically. If there is a wrong id, wouldn't it display an error in the program?

Comment: It may, but it may not. Just search for `dp` and look where it is not mentioned as dimension. There is a very good chance that you will spot the problem very quickly...

Comment: Ok I will do that now.  Also the error occurs when I add tabs       tabHost.addTab(spec);   So something might be wrong with adding the tabs on the bottom